# How to validate fields in angular js (not blank)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple `input` fields and I want to validate my `fields`. They can't b blank when user click on `submit` button. How I will show `border red` when user click on button if fields are empty.

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/XtnSdO9ARpHdn9RZotMt?p=info

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.c = [
    {
      name:'abc'
    },
    {
      name:'pqr'
    }
    ];

    $scope.onclick =function(){

      console.log($scope.c)
    }

});
```

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#using-css-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to use `required` attribute on your fields. But you can do manual validation with a directive. You just need to wrap your inputs in a `<form>`. This directive can be extended to do any validation you want. Here is an example of one:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.c = [{
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    name: 'pqr'
  }];

  $scope.onclick = function() {
    console.log($scope.c)
  }
});

app.directive("emptyValidator", function($q, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

      ctrl.$validators.empty = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (!ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.12/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form name="formName" ng-submit="onclick()">
      <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>

      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in c">
          <ng-form name="innerForm">
            <input type="text" name="inputName" ng-model='x.name' empty-validator ng-class="{'red-border' : innerForm.inputName.$error.empty}" />
          </ng-form>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**However**, you asked for a weird request to validate it on a click of a button, so you might want to do it in the function itself. Which is not a proper way to validate it, but still can be done. Here is an example of that:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.c = [{
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    name: 'pqr'
  }];
  $scope.d = [false, false];

  $scope.onclick = function() {
    var f = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.c.length; i++) {
      if (!$scope.c[i].name) {
        $scope.d[i] = true;
        f = true;
      } else {
        $scope.d[i] = false;
      }
    }
    if (f) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log($scope.c)
  }
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.12/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form ng-submit="onclick()">
      <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>

      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in c">
          <input type="text" ng-model='x.name' ng-class="{'red-border' : d[$index]}" />
        </li>
      </ul>

    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to put all input fields inside form tag. Like this:

```
<form ng-submit="onclick()">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <li ng-repeat="x in c">
    <input type="text" ng-model='x.name' value="{{x.name=='abc'?'ddd':'hhh'}}" required="true"/>
   </li>
</form>
```

For input's you need to set property required="true" (or angular's ng-required, if you need conditional values). Sumbit button need to have type="submit" (so he triggers form submission). Submit function needs to be moved from button on-click to form's property ng-submit="onclick()".

This example will already work with native html5 validation messages.
If you want to add custom styles, input's which are not valid will have css class ('ng-invalid') on them.